# Importing modules that import other modules from other directories in Python 3.6

Tags: python, import, module

I have a working directory that looks like this:

```
project
  src
    data
      +secrets.py
      +data.py
    +format.py
```

I have variables in `secrets.py` called `user` and `pw`.

I import the variables in `data.py` to connect to a database like so:

```
from secrets import user, pw
```

This works, but now I want to be able to run this from within `format.py`:

```
from data.data import <function_name>
```

I get an `Import Error: cannot import name 'user' from 'secrets'`

Since `format.py` is not in the same directory as `data.py`, the import is breaking because it cannot find a `secrets.py`. If I were to update `data.py` with this:

```
from data.secrets import user, pw
```

I could successfully run `format.py`. But then that would break `data.py`!

I feel like I am just completely structuring my project wrong from the jump. Is there are better way to do this or a way to fix the import errors?

I have tried using relative imports with `..` and explicitly using `src.data.secrets` but that will still break `data.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try `from .secrets import user, pw`. I tried, it works. The dot means you are importing module from the current directory

Comment: This only works when running format.py. When I run data.py I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.secrets'; '__main__' is not a package

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```py
from importlib import import_module

format = import_module("../format.py")
```

You may have to use and probably should according to the docs.

```py
from importlib import import_module

format = exec_module(create_module(find_spec("../format.py)))
```